Removing installed keyboard and (or) restoring keyboard list to default
Under windows 10, I created a custom keyboard layout using MSKLC. Then I modified it, reinstalled it, modified it again...
Today, I have 5 different version of my custom keyboard installed, all have the same name, I don't know which does what, and none of them are useful. The associated setup.exe and .msi files have been lost.
I would like to uninstall ALL of them. Or, if needed, just restore the full keyboard list (or language settings) to default. Is that possible?
